# redirecting wordpress site to https works but not for pages and posts

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to setup https rule in `.htaccess` file so whoever access my website gets redirected to https and to achieve this, this is how my `htaccess` file looks like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The above works fine how home page but if i access a page directly `domain.com/page` then i dont get redirected to https

Can someone please tell me what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `RewriteRule` to

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Notice, there's no `$` after `^`, which was effectively stating that redirect but only if no directory path information is found i.e. redirect root URL `/` requests only.